# How to merge assiocative arrays inside numerical array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, array-merge

Good day! I am having errors in merging/combining/concatenating arrays.

For example I have arrays,

```
$array1 [] = array(
'var1' => $var1,
'var2' => $var2,
'var3' => $var3,
);
$array2 [] = array(
'var4' => $var4,
'var5' => $var5,
'var6' => $var6,
);
```

Those arrays have multiple records inside of them but have the same number of records.
When i var_dump them the structure looks like this:

```
//array1
array(3){
    [0]=>array(3){
        ["var1"]=> string (4) "var1"
        ["var2"]=> string (4) "var2"
        ["var3"]=> string (4) "var3"
    }
    [1]=>array(3){
        ["var1"]=> string (4) "var1"
        ["var2"]=> string (4) "var2"
        ["var3"]=> string (4) "var3"
    }
    [2]=>array(3){
        ["var1"]=> string (4) "var1"
        ["var2"]=> string (4) "var2"
        ["var3"]=> string (4) "var3"
    }
}
//array2
array(3){
    [0]=>array(3){
        ["var4"]=> string (4) "var4"
        ["var5"]=> string (4) "var5"
        ["var6"]=> string (4) "var6"
    }
    [1]=>array(3){
        ["var4"]=> string (4) "var4"
        ["var5"]=> string (4) "var5"
        ["var6"]=> string (4) "var6"
    }
    [2]=>array(3){
        ["var4"]=> string (4) "var4"
        ["var5"]=> string (4) "var5"
        ["var6"]=> string (4) "var6"
    }
}
```

I want to add both arrays

```
$array_combined [] = array(
'var1' => $var1,
'var2' => $var2,
'var3' => $var3,
'var4' => $var4,
'var5' => $var5,
'var6' => $var6,
);
```

I think the structure should look like this when var_dump(ed):

```
//array_combined
array(3){
    [0]=>array(6){
        ["var1"]=> string (4) "var1"
        ["var2"]=> string (4) "var2"
        ["var3"]=> string (4) "var3"
        ["var4"]=> string (4) "var4"
        ["var5"]=> string (4) "var5"
        ["var6"]=> string (4) "var6"

    }
    [1]=>array(3){
        ["var1"]=> string (4) "var1"
        ["var2"]=> string (4) "var2"
        ["var3"]=> string (4) "var3"
        ["var4"]=> string (4) "var4"
        ["var5"]=> string (4) "var5"
        ["var6"]=> string (4) "var6"

    }
    [2]=>array(3){
        ["var1"]=> string (4) "var1"
        ["var2"]=> string (4) "var2"
        ["var3"]=> string (4) "var3"
        ["var4"]=> string (4) "var4"
        ["var5"]=> string (4) "var5"
        ["var6"]=> string (4) "var6"
    }
}
```

I tried:

```
 $array_combine = array_combine($array1, $array2);
 $array_merge = array_merge($array1, $array2);
 $array_merge_recursive = array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);
```

but i keep getting this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: cmax in D:\xampp\htdocs\vra\GetVM - Copy.php on line 365

The code that i posted there is just similar to my real code.
Line 365 contains echo ( $record['var4'] ).
I was doing something like this to output the combined/merged array.

`$array_merge = merge_array($array1, $array2)`
`foreach ( $array_merge as $record ) {`
`echo ( $record['var1'] );`
`echo ( $record['var2'] );`
`echo ( $record['var3'] );`
`echo ( $record['var4'] );//this is were the error occurs`
`echo ( $record['var5'] );//same error here`
`echo ( $record['var6'] );//same error here`
`}`

Tried using array_combine(),array_merge_recursive and $combined_array = $array1 + $array2

Comment: Actually the code that i posted there is just similar to my real code.  <br/>
Line 365 contains echo ( $record['var4'] ).  <br/>
I was doing something like this to output the combined/merged array.     <br/> 
$array_merge = merge_array($array1, $array2)  <br/>
    foreach ( $array_merge as $record ) {  <br/>
        echo ( $record['var1'] );  <br/>
        echo ( $record['var2'] );  <br/>
        echo ( $record['var3'] );  <br/>
        echo ( $record['var4'] );//this is were the error occurs  <br/> 
        echo ( $record['var5'] );  <br/>
        echo ( $record['var6'] );  <br/>
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the issue is stemming from you using multidimensional arrays and trying to combine them as single dimension arrays.

Instead of

```
$array_merge = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

Try

```
$array_merge[0] = array_merge($array1[0], $array2[0]);
$array_merge[1] = array_merge($array1[1], $array2[1]);
$array_merge[2] = array_merge($array1[2], $array2[2]);
[ ... ]
```

If you want to strictly combine them and never overright values from the first with the second, use

```
$array_merge = $array1 + $array2;
```

Some additional notes on array merging can be found at [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: You're welcome :) Please mark this as the correct answer if it is such. Thanks!